# peformance.getEntries() and negative duration display

Tags: javascript, metrics

**SOLVED:**

I am using 'performance.getEntries()' and in some instances, I am getting negative duration numbers. I find this odd, because I know the items loaded. I was under the assumption that a negative duration represented the fact that the resource did not load and responseEnd is 0.

Mind you, I am seeing a few of these - most do have proper durations, but I am curious about these.
When would duration be a negative number when I know the resource loaded? cached perhaps?

I read this: 
"*The duration attribute must return a DOMHighResTimeStamp that contains the time value of the duration of the entire event being recorded by this PerformanceEntry. Typically, this would be the time difference between the last recorded timestamp and the first recorded timestamp of this PerformanceEntry. A performance metric may choose to return a duration of 0, if the duration concept doesn't apply.*"

So, to me: "..the duration concept doesn't apply" <-- when would that happen on one resource, but not on another IF both have loaded? (btw: these resources reside on the server in question, same domain).

Now, what is odd is that what might give me a negative result on one page, gives me a proper result on a different page.

```
loadStart | round Duration | Duration

   695    | -250888        | -250887.99999997718 

   696    | -250858        |  -250858.00000000745 

   697    | -250846        | -250846.00000001956
```

AFTER SOME INVESTIGATION:
It appears that the negative durations can and do load their respective resources, it just loads 'after' loadEndTime. In other words, loads after the page has 'ended' - loaded. I was thinking that performance API would keep a running tab of the assets/resources. So if I called to it sometime after load, then it would give me an accurate reading "up to that point". Seems that once loadEnds, the API's values are cemented.