# PerformanceObserver mark api with negative duration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, performance-testing

I am trying to get some accurate `marks` around execution time of certain JS apis of my React code. I see [this in the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/user-timing-3/)

```js
Set entry's duration attribute to the duration from start time to end time. 
The resulting duration value MAY be negative.
```

I am curious as to why some of these `durations` are negative. That is, I start the `mark` in code, and end the `mark` at a time that is necessarily later. My whole purpose is to capture the duration, so I am a bit confused as to the results.

```js
const k = 'EXAMPLE_KEY';
const start = `start:${k}`;
const end = `end:${k}`;


//// Parent React Component
performance.mark(start);

/// Child Component, which happens to be an img
const onLoad = () => {
   performance.mark(end);
   const result = performance.measure(k, start, stop);
   /// Yields negative duration
}
```

What are some considerations as to when a `duration` is negative?

[Here is a very similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191918/peformance-getentries-and-negative-duration-display), but that one is unanswered and not dealing w/ manual `start/stop`. Any help is appreciated!